# Undefine showing in $.ajax at mouse over when debugging and value not pass

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get my values from a field by ajax but ajax don't work and when I debug it in Firefox then at `$.ajax` is showing `undefined`.

Check this link please for my browser debug option http://prntscr.com/m8xnxy

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var search = $("#names").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/ajax/shakil.php",
      data: { search: search },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
<form class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      id="names"
      aria-describedby="emailHelp"
      placeholder="Enter email"
    />
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" name="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery you're using

Comment: @executable is stating that the `slim` version of jquery doesn't include ajax.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was OP that answered

Comment: I am using updated JQuery version but My problem is $.ajax is showing undefined while I try to debug